# "current_user" variable scope confusion following RoR tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, railstutorial.org

Note: before I started the tutorial at railstutorial.org, I completed codecademy's Ruby tutorial.

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial. I'm on chapter 8, and I'm on the sessions_helper.rb file. There's a variable called "current_user". I learned about scope when following the Ruby tutorial, but now I'm having trouble applying what I learned.

In the tutorial, there is the following code:

```
module SessionsHelper
    def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user=(user)
       @current_user = user 
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
    end
end
```

In particular, what I don't understand is the difference between

a) self.current_user
b) @current_user
c) current_user

I have an understanding of global, instance, and local variables in concept, but not in application. If I were to code this by myself without the training wheels of the tutorial, I wouldn't know when to use which. Could somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` if you do not explicitly declare a local variable, it will look for a method in the current scope, in this case your `def current_user` method.

`@current_user` is an instance variable. One of Rails magics is to copy all the instance variables from the controller into views. In this case, it probably comes from your controller or `ApplicationController`, which it probably inherits from.

`self.current_user` is the same as `current_user`, except that `self.current_user=` in your code means you're using the method declared right below it instead of assigning a local variable.

i.e.

```
current_user = "pedro"
current_user # "pedro"
self.current_user # method called
```

In case of not declaring a local variable, this is what happens with `current_user`:

```
current_user # method called
self.current_user # same method called
```

Comment: a few specific questions I was able to come up with
a) why can't you replace (in the code in my question) "self.current_user=user" with "@current_user=user"?

b) in the "signed_in?" method, why don't you have to say "!self.current_user.nil?" or "!@current_user.nil?" the loca variable "current_user" isn't defined

Comment: a) You could, however it's best practice to use an assignment method when one is available. In the future that method may do things other than simply assigning an instance variable. For instance, have a look at the `current_user` method - it's not just fetching `@current_user`, it's doing other stuff as well.
b) Ruby does an implicit `self.` on such a method call (i.e. when a local variable isn't available), as shown in the last part of the answer.